# Jquery Sorttable Fixed table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am using JQuery  sorttable for sorting table data asc or dsc order. When I am click a table header its sorts data. 
For example http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Now I want keep a row fixed . For example first row . No matter what column I clicked it will be stay fixed . Is this possible in JQuery sorttable ?

Comment: Add `Css` - `thead:{position:fixed}`

Comment: I want to fixed a row below thead  .

Comment: Then you need to show your table structure first.. Post some `html`

Comment: Please visit this link . 
http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Suppose i want to fixed the row below  . It stay fixed no matter what sorting is done 



Bloggs, Fred $12000.00 1353 18/08/2003 08/18/2003